# How do I get out of iPhone's Safe Mode (jailbroken)?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios, safe-mode

I just did something REALLY stupid. I was following the instructions on how to get into Safe Mode (on YouTube). The guy in the video says to first shut down my iPhone, then press and hold Volume up button first and then press and hold Power button to boot it up. Once the Apple logo appears, I continue to hold it for 5 seconds and yes, my iPhone booted into Safe Mode. The video also says if you want to get out of Safe Mode, just do a reset (Press and hold Power button + Home button) But it did not work, my phone is blank now, no icons, no Cydia, no Settings, no Messages, nothing at all, except for Newsstand.

Please help me, I don't know what to do :(

PS: iTunes didn't detect any problem (until when I'm trying to back up, it says an error occured).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go back into Safe Mode by holding both power and home until you get the Apple logo, then immediately hold volume up.
2. Open Cydia and reinstall Cydia Substrate and Substrate Safe Mode.
3. Reboot.

Comment: I tried and Cydia still didn't appear.